# Bootstrap text-align right for navigation at breakpoint

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile

Right now I have my navigation links centering themselves on a large display.

[image]

However, at the breakpoint and when the menu button comes up I'd like for the menu items to align themselves right. It just doesn't look right like this.

[image]

Also a way to remove that little white line right above the navigation links would be great, I'm not sure where it comes from. Thanks!

Check the issue out at https://willhay.io/masonry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me the menu looks better as it is, centered.
However here is the code for the way you like it:

```
 @media only screen and (max-width : 780px) {
    .noStyle li {
        display:block;
        text-align: right;
    }
    .noStyle {
        float: right !important;
    }
    .navbar-collapse {
        -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.1);
            box-shadow: inset 0 0px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.1);
    }
 }
```

Change the "780px" to your prefered width.

Comment: Ya after looking at it, center aligning does look much better. The only problem now is getting the dropdown menu for projects to work like it does on https://willhay.io. Right now it messes with the formatting of the nav on mobile, and the colors are also off.

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra-class, line 78 of your test.css, that displays inline li items in your menu. You need to remove that class from your menu items of from CSS. Then you can float your items. To do that you have to remove inline block from your UL declarations you've done on line 23 and set LI items to text-align: right;